# Accessing and updating sharepoint list using SOAP/REST

Tags: list, 2007, rest, soap

I have been searching and researching a problem I have been tasked with for a few days and figured now is the time to ask for help.  I am a C# Application developer and have the following task.

In my data center, I have a SQL database full of information.

On another network at another installation, there is a Sharepoint site, I do not administer the site but do have admin privileges to read and write.

What I am hoping to accomplish is to write an application or a job that will take data from my SQL database and update the sharepoint list (again on another network).

The list is located on a URL like `https://MYSITE/DIR/1/1-2/Lists/Test/AllItems.aspx`

I have tried to access the list several ways using (`_vti_bin/ListData.svc`) such as:

- `https://MYSITE/_vti_bin/ListData.svc` -

  > An error has occurred on the server.
- `https://MYSITE/DIR/1/1-2/Lists/Test/AllItems.aspx/_vti_bin/ListData.svc` - Just shows the list

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what edition & version of SharePoint (2007/2010/2013) and SQL Server ?

Comment: SP 2007 (soon to be 2010) and SQL 2005 (I don't have authority to upgrade that yet)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, WSS 3.0 / MOSS 2007 does not support REST. You should use the "classic" web service (SOAP) approach via the [UpdateListItems](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.lists.updatelistitems(v=office.12).aspx) method of the [Lists web service](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Lists(v=office.12).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative that may be worth exploring is to use SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS). There's package on Codeplex that integrates SharePoint with SQL Server for data integration. See here for more details -

[Accessing SharePoint Lists with SQL Server Integration Services SSIS 2005](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1733/accessing-sharepoint-lists-with-sql-server-integration-services-ssis-2005/)

[Extracting and Loading SharePoint Data in SQL Server Integration Services](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh368261.aspx)